# How to invert the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Calculate the inverse of the $(m+1)\times(m+1)$ matrix:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & n & n^2 & \cdots & n^m \\ 
1 & n+1 & (n+1)^2 & \cdots & (n+1)^m \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\[4pt]
1 & n+m & (n+m)^2 & \cdots & (n+m)^m \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: The position $(2,3)$ seems to be $(n+1)^2$. Moreover try sharing where you are lost. So we can help you get the right direction.

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde_Matrix